# C# делегат в качестве параметра. Использование лямбда выражения

Tags: c#, lambda, делегаты

Доброго времени суток.

Есть класс:

```
class TestClass
{
    public int val { get; set; }
   
    public TestClass() { }
}
```

Есть метод:

```
private void MyProc(Action<TestClass> p)
{            
       // ???????????????????????
}
```

Хочу делать вот так:

```
MyProc(p => p.val = 2);
```

Только не понимаю, как мне получить объект класса TestClass в MyProc и далее что то делать исходя из значения val.

Comment: Если что, в лямбде нет объекта класса. Туда его нужно передать. Внутри MyProc создаёте объект `var tc = new TestClass();` и вызываете `p(tc)`. Но вам явно нужно не это. Уточните сценарий использования.

Comment: я конечно могу создать экземпляр класса и сделать на входе MyProc TestClass, но меня именно интересует тот пример который я указал. Интересует как обработать значение если на входе делегат, а задавать я должен через лямбда.

Comment: Покажите (можно псевдокодом), как и что вы хотите делать. Сейчас совершенно непонятно.

Comment: я же писал выше как и что я хочу делать. Вот яркий пример. Как они далее работают с endopints внутри UseEndpoints? `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });`

Comment: Не пишите код в комментариях. Перенесите его в вопрос.